# -webkit-text-size-adjust is no longer supported,how to set font-size to less than 12px

Tags: css, webkit, font-size

When I update my chrome to **28.0.1500.11 dev-m**, I found that:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
```

is no longer supported,and I found the changlist here http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/145168

It`s not work in chrome when I set the CSS like this:

```
font-size:10px;//number less than 12
```

In chrome (version:28.0.1500.11 dev-m) the font-size it`s also `12px`

I tried this:

```
font-size:10px;
-webkit-transform:scale(0.83);
display:inline-block;
```

I know it`s maybe not the right way to fix that issue

thank you for your help

Comment: There's nothing stopping you setting any size you like in your CSS. It's not clear what the issue is here.

Comment: If the user has chosen to set a minimum font size via their browser's configuration, there's nothing you can do to override this.

Comment: @ralph.m I`m sorry for not clearly describe my issue,I mean that chrome has set a minimum font size(default 12px),but we need to set some number to 10px(in some situations)

Comment: @cimmanon yeah,but in some situation,like we just want to rank something and we need the rank number to be smaller than the main text(12px)

Comment: Why is your main text 12px?  For many users, that's uncomfortably small.  Again, there's nothing you can do about this.  The CSS specificity goes in this order: UA defaults > Author styles (yours) > User styles.  If the user says anything smaller than 12px is too small for them to read, it doesn't make a lot of sense for you to be able to override adjustments they've made for accessibility reasons.  See also:  http://filamentgroup.com/lab/how_we_learned_to_leave_body_font_size_alone/

Comment: Is the actual default minimum size 12px? I have 29.0.1508.3 canary, and have never adjusted the minimum font-size, but it is set to 6px.

Comment: I`ve just downloaded the lastest canary(29.0.1509.3 canary),the default minimum size is 12px,but we can adjust it to 6px.@Whitelaw

Comment: Can someone advise? I tested it on Chrome 27 but still couldn't make the font size smaller than 12px.

Answer (score 2):

This trick helped me to solve:

> Setting a max-height greater then the elements height on one of the parents elements seems to resolve this issue.

Found here: http://davemacaulay.com/webkit-text-size-adjust-doesnt-work-on-android-chrome/

Answer (score -2):

It's better to set your font's in em units, especially for mobile. This way you can easily target all em's with an media query or something. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp