# Problems using em units in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-size

I've got a problem when using em units in Chrome (Version 31.0.1650.63 m).

Following JSFiddle produces incorrect output in Chrome (in comparison to Firefox or IE the green box is too big):

http://jsfiddle.net/rapik/j72aZ/

HTML:

```
<div class="aaa">

    <div class="bbb">

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.aaa {
    font-size: 0.5rem;

    width: 30em;
    height: 30em;

    background: red;
}

.bbb {
    font-size: 0.1em;

    width: 15em;
    height: 15em;

    background: green;
}
```

The problem seem to be the rule `font-size: 0.1em` which does not make the em 10 times smaller. Instead it sets em to some minimum value. There will be no difference between `font-size: 0.1em` and `font-size: 0.2em` because both are smaller than this magic minimum value....

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

This particular case can be solved by multiplying all values of the "bbb" class with 10. But in my case the thing is more complicated and I need this `font-size: 0.1em`.

I am using em units to build scalable controls. My controls have root div and multiple child elements. The idea is that all values are set using em and the run-time size of the em is controlled by the font-size of the root element. If an element has font-size defined, then it's em will depend on it.

I would appreciate any ideas or suggestions!

**Update:**

Here are screenshots of different outputs I am speaking about:

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Firefox (26), Chrome (31.0.1650.63 m), and Opera (Presto) all render the green box as being 1/4 the size of the red box.  Only IE9 renders the green box as being exceptionally small.

Comment: @cimmanon: Which OS? I'm seeing the 12x12 green box in FF 26, Windows 7.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 as well.

Comment: The green box should be quite small. I've added illustration.

Comment: The green box is really small in Firefox 50 (Linux), but bigger in Chrome 53 (Linux).

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by the fact that the *minimum font-size* setting is floored at 6px (in Chrome 30+) - you can't choose a lower value. This isn't problematic when you set the font-size of `.aaa`, as its computed value is 8px. But  using `font-size: 0.1em;` on `.bbb` results in a computed value of **0.8px** - and since it's less than the minium, the actual used value is 6px:

http://linenwoods.com/images/dev.png

[This](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=229354) bug report, though slightly unrelated, suggested changing the minimum font-size setting to something larger, pressing done, and then changing it back to 6px (though it didn't seem to work for your example.) It also mentioned that prior to Chrome 27, you were [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295095/font-size-12px-doesnt-have-effect-in-google-chrome/4316700#4316700) able to get around this with `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` (though it's been deprecated as of version 27.) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589785/webkit-text-size-adjust-is-no-longer-supported-how-to-set-font-size-to-less-tha), somewhat recent question, seeks a similar solution but has yet to been answered.

Comment: This is something! But after Phlume answer I tried setting the font size of the `.aaa` using pixels ("12px" instead of "0.1rem") and it helped. The computed size of `.bbb` is `1px` now... Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rapik/j72aZ/5/

Comment: @Andrej: The computed style of `.bbb` is still showing 6px for me (in that fiddle).

Comment: Interesting. I checked again and I see "1px" for `.bbb` (Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m on Win Server 2012). Do you get a small green box (like 15x15 px) or a big one?

Comment: I get the original 90x90 box (Chrome 31.0.1650.63, Windows 7)

Answer (score 2):

As 412 has explained, this is due to the Chrome minimum font size of `6px`, though I'll add that this font size only kicks in when the font sizes are specified using `em` or `rem`. Either you can accept this limitation, or you can sidestep it.

Say you are targeting a root font size of 1px when 1 em = 16px (i.e. most browsers), you might think to use rules like:

```
html { font-size: 0.0625em }
.myElem { height: 20em; font-size: 12em; }
```

as I have previously done (logic being that your container height needs to scale depending on font size). On Chrome, it seems that here `font-size` will equate as `12 * 1px = 12px` as expected, however height will calculate as `20 * 6px = 300px`, using the minimum font size of `6px`, which is of course undesirable.

Instead, you can use the following approach:

```
html { font-size: calc(1em / 16); }
.myElem { height: 20em; font-size: 12em; }
```

Your root element (`<html>`) font size still calculates to `1px` when `1 em = 16px`, however as it's in px instead of `em`/`rem`, the minimum font size rule of `6px` doesn't come into play, and height will equal `20px` as desired.

**Warning**

I've recently discovered that this doesn't work with some non-English languages, like Bulgarian or Cantonese. Personally I've dropped interest in using `em` after learning that major websites like Facebook etc don't use them, instead users who want bigger text can just use a zoom setting either at the browser or OS level.

Answer (score 1):

Since the default font size is what the `em` size refers to you need to declare a size for the font in order for the em to be universal.

http://jsfiddle.net/j72aZ/1/

This fiddle declares a font-size globally as 12px and then the browser treats the em size universally to that 12px, as opposed to the undeclared size which is the users' browser's default.

This site has some good material that may be able to assist you further:

http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: Your description sounds like you are speaking about rem not em. em depends on font size of the parent element. Nevertheless your example fixes problem in my example. Actually it's enough to set the font size of the aaa class in pixels instead of setting it using rem: http://jsfiddle.net/rapik/j72aZ/5/ I'll do more tests later :-)