# How to get rid of space above a span if parent's font-size is huge?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I've got a situation where a parent DOM-element has a quite large em-value. The problem is that all inline child elements get a huge margin above them even if their font-size is much smaller:

[image]

Source (http://jsfiddle.net/rapik/w87m7/2/):

```
<div style="font-size: 100px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <span style="font-size: 0.1em;">How to get rid of the space above without changing the font-size or display properties?</span>
</div>
```

How can I get rid of this gap without changing the font-size? I also don't want to change element's display type to "block".

I've tried changing the line-height but did not succeed.

P. S. In case you wonder, why I need this: Chrome has a "feature" which prevents font-size be smaller than 6 pixels at any time. So I multiplied all values by ten and got this problem. Corresponding question: [Problems using em units in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120922/problems-using-em-units-in-chrome)

Comment: It is unclear what you want. If you want the box height to be smaller, the question arises why you don’t say that and why don’t try setting it.

Comment: @Jukka, because I have different point of view on this problem and because simply setting the height of the div does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that the font-size on the div leads to an according line-height; hence tha 'gap'.

So setting the line-height to the actual font-size that you plan to use in the span will remove it in a combination with the already mentioned vertical-align:

```
<div style="font-size: 100px; border: 1px solid red; line-height: 0.1em;">
<span style="font-size: 0.1em;vertical-align:top">How to get rid of the space above     without changing the font-size or display properties?</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `vertical-align:top`, otherwise child elements will align to the baseline.

Comment: this *is* the answer...if `display` type is not supposed to be changed!! :)

Comment: @Andrej why don't you just set the font size on the parent to a smaller size then???

Comment: @Andrej can you give some detail as to what you are trying to do, there might be a better approach

Answer (score 0):

This added `height` and `vertical align` should take care of it for you.

```
<div style="height: 25px;font-size: 100px; border: 1px solid red;">
<span style="font-size: 0.1em;vertical-align:top;">How to get rid of the space above without changing the font-size or display properties?</span>
</div>
```